# Generic contraints

Tags: c#, generics

I've got a class that I want to enforce some generic constraints on when created

Myobject.cs

```
    public class MyObject<T> where T : ObjectBase, new()
    {
        public MyObject()
        {
        }

        public bool Validate(out ServiceError? message)
        {
            // validation
        }
    }
```

ObjectBase.cs

```
public abstract class ObjectBase
{
    public abstract bool Validate(out ServiceError? message);
}
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to avoid having to place generic constraints for T every time I have a function such as this:

ObjectRepo.cs

```
public void Put<T>(MyObject<T> obj)
  where T : ObjectBase, new()
{
    // code
}
```

If the constraints for T are specified in the MyObject class, is there a reason I have to re-specify every single time I use MyObject as a parameter?

Answer (score 6):

Don't redefine T on your method if you have it on the class

```
public class MyObject<T> where T : ObjectBase, new()
{
    //public void Put<T>(MyObject<T> obj)//doesn't work
    public void Put(MyObject<T> obj)//works
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

**Update**
If Put is in another class your best solution it to refactor your code and move all the T related method in the same class (and add the constrain on the class)

**Update 2**
If update 1 is not possible ,it might worth checking if you can replace your T with ObjectBase or another base class

Comment: "The type or namespace 'T' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: Just saw your edit, the Put function is in a different class, not within the MyObject class